# Why automatically remove the tridion:href="tcm:8-299" property from anchor tag?

Tags: dynamic-linking, linking

I have a Component which contains HTML with the following anchor tag

```html
<a href="dummy.html" tridion:href="tcm:8-299">...</a>
```

When I save the Component then I get the following content

```html
<a href="dummy.html">...</a>
```

It automatically removed the `tridion:href` property why?

Comment: are you trying to create a component link in richtext field? or please explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you simply use Tridion GUI to create a link in richtext field?

It should result something like this:

```
<a href="tcm:8-299" title="component Title">TEST</a>
```

Try using it.

AFAIK : the `tridion:href` is used in DWT and the links are resolved by linkResolver.

Comment: correct indeed, in a RTF you simply use `href="tcm:1-2"` and in a DWT TBB you have to use `tridion:href="tcm:1-2"`

Comment: I think previously i was doing wrong but right now i create a anchor tag using sdl gui in RTF and it is working when i preview the page in sdl but when i publish my page it showing nothing only showing ? sign on page at place of anchor tag

Comment: what are you writing in Template TBB to resolve this link? if you are using DWT use somthing like `<a tridion:href="tcm:8-299" title="" >`, as Brat suggested. and if it not resolved after this, go through @Nick's Answar.

Comment: @pankaj if you don't see anything on the Published page, check out Nickoli Roussakov's answer. Dynamic Links will only work on a dynamic page (.aspx or .jsp or the likes) and your Component Template must have the correct output too (REL is often the best choice).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you were in the rich text editor and entering HTML ... the RTE will tidy up invalid HTML syntax.  `tridion:href` does not exist in any HTML implementation and is a custom tag so is likely just removed.

This if memory serves, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because Dynamic Linking cannot resolve the component link to a published page.  Make sure that the component you're linking exists on a page published within the same context.

Another reason could be that your component template is set to be dynamic with the HTML Fragment output format.  If so, make sure it is REL.